# Mysql, selecting same column for multiple values, different criteria

Tags: mysql, multi-select

I am having trouble figuring out how to create multiple selects with where clauses so that I have a column for each of the three scenarios in my name field.

The query I have now is:

```
    SELECT
    pd_extrafields.packetDetailsId,
    pd_extrafields.ex_value as Credit 
    FROM
    pd_extrafields
    where pd_extrafields.ex_title = "Credit,A,B,C,D,E,F"
```

How can I pull in the other two columns into the same query with the following conditions (basically I want to combine the three queries into one and keep the column names):

```
    SELECT
    pd_extrafields.packetDetailsId,
    pd_extrafields.ex_value as AccountNum 
    FROM
    pd_extrafields
    where pd_extrafields.ex_title = "Account#"
```

&

```
    SELECT
    pd_extrafields.packetDetailsId,
    pd_extrafields.ex_value as OrderStat 
    FROM
    pd_extrafields
    where pd_extrafields.ex_title = "New/Existing"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE`.

```
 select packetDetailsId, GROUP_CONCAT(Credit) AS Credit, GROUP_CONCAT(AccountNum) AS AccountNum, GROUP_CONCAT(OrderStat) AS OrderStat FROM
( SELECT pd_extrafields.packetDetailsId,
    CASE WHEN pd_extrafields.ex_title LIKE ('%Credit%') 
    THEN pd_extrafields.ex_value ELSE NULL END as Credit,
    CASE WHEN pd_extrafields.ex_title LIKE ('%Account%') 
    THEN pd_extrafields.ex_value ELSE NULL END as AccountNum,
    CASE WHEN pd_extrafields.ex_title LIKE ('%Existing%') 
    THEN pd_extrafields.ex_value ELSE NULL END as OrderStat
    FROM pd_extrafields) AS TempTab GROUP BY packetDetailsId
```

Comment: Thank you Ravindra for the quick reply. It almost works, I get an error and then removed the comma after "OrderStat" which seems to help however it doesn't return any values for that columns. Also is there a way to consolidate/group it so the results appear on one line/row per 'packetDetailsId'?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Edited my query. I think it will be displayed one row per packet details id unless you have same packet details id in different rows. Isn't it? what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Here is a link to the sql fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa2a3/1  also it's not including any output for the OrderStat Column.

Comment: In your case, you have to use `LIKE` instead of `=`. Updated the query. and fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa2a3/4

Comment: Again thank you Ravindra, however it seems to only provide one result even if there are results for all three cases. Does it have something to do with grouping?

Comment: Can you point an example in that fiddle so that I can quickly check? I tried with simple words in the query. Check the updated query.

Comment: Also I understood what you are asking about grouping. Let me see if I can do that.

Comment: I appreciate your tenacity! Our messages had momentarily crossed. I'm going to dig into this so I can make sense of it, thank you again :)

Comment: Yes it is coming with the latest query which I had given.